# Can not kill a YARN application through REST api

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm using Hadoop 2.5.0 (CDH 5.3.5).

Following [this document](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_State_API), I tried to kill a running YARN application (whose application id is *application_1438849897472_0011*) through the following REST api:

`curl -i -XPUT http://{rm-rest-host}:{rm-rest-port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1438849897472_0011/killed`

But I got a status code of 404 and an exception message complaining about

> org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /v1/cluster/apps/application_1438849897472_0011/killed: controller for v1 not found

So what is going wrong ?

Answer (score 4):

The correct URI ends with `/state`, not `/killed` and you are missing the request body.

Try this:

```
curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"state": "KILLED"}' 'http://{rm-rest-host}:{rm-rest-port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/{app-id}/state'
```

Answer (score -2):

Try the following:

```
curl -v -X PUT -d '{"state": "KILLED"}''http://{rm-rest-host}:{rm-rest-port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/application_1438849897472_0011/state'
```

The [documentation you linked](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html#Cluster_Application_State_API) states:

> With the application state API, you can query the state of a submitted app as well kill a running app by modifying the state of a running app using a PUT request with the state set to "KILLED". To perform the PUT operation, authentication has to be setup for the RM web services. In addition, you must be authorized to kill the app. Currently you can only change the state to "KILLED"; an attempt to change the state to any other results in a 400 error response. Examples of the unauthorized and bad request errors are below. When you carry out a successful PUT, the iniital response may be a 202. You can confirm that the app is killed by repeating the PUT request until you get a 200, querying the state using the GET method or querying for app information and checking the state. [...]

Comment: I tried your answer and still got that same exception. **Perhaps I  need to do something about authentication ?**  I noticed the following content in the document:

"To perform the PUT operation, authentication has to be setup for the RM web services. In addition, you must be authorized to kill the app."

Comment: You'd have received an 'UNAUTHORIZED' response, if it's was an authentication issue.

Comment: Here is [the response](http://7xjcu2.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/QQ20150809-1@2x.png)

Comment: Can you query the status of the app with a GET?

Comment: Can you check YARN's log, server side, to see if something appear when you're sending the kill command?

Comment: Note that you initially had a 404 error and now a 500

Comment: Checking YARN's log, I found [the exception part](http://pastebin.ca/3094978).    

When I invoked the API in the form of *curl -i -X PUT http://{rm-rest-host}:{rm-rest-port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/{appId}/killed*, I would get a 404 error, and an exception like *org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.WebAppException: /v1/cluster/apps/application_1438849897472_0015/Killed: controller for v1 not found*. 

When I invoked the API in the form of *curl -i -X PUT -d '{"state":"Killed"}'  http://{rm-rest-host}:{rm-rest-port}/ws/v1/cluster/apps/{appId}*, I would get a 500 error.

Comment: So at this point, this is a totally different question. The answer I gave is the solution to the question you asked( i.e the reason of the 404.) Now it seems that we reason of this exception comes from your application, which we don't know about. What about closing this question and opening a new one with details of your code?

Comment: I don't have any application myself -  I just sent a REST request to the YARN Resource Manager, so the exception, if there is any, must come from the Resource Manager itself. Yet thank you very much for your answer @Bacon.

Comment: I would say that the exception comes from the application which is ran by YARN, if this last was not modified. A similar exception can be seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15093046/ajax-post-header. Anyway, if you think that the answer satisfies your initial question, please consider accepting it :-)