# How to kill an EMR task programatically

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I want to programtically kill an EMR streaming task. If I kill it from EMR UI or boto client, it disappears in EMR, but it is still active in the Hadoop cluster (see [this article](https://medium.com/everything-full-stack/emr-hadoop-dissonance-330f322a1d40)). Only if I go through the Hadoop resource manager and kill it from there, the job is terminated.
How can do the same programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @maxime-g said, the only way to kill a yarn application is to run the following command: `yarn application -kill application_id`.
But it is possible to run an EMR which runs a script on the master node, and that script should include this command, and possible take an argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can `ssh` to cluster and use `yarn application -kill application_id` or use yarn api to kill application

[Can not kill a YARN application through REST api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868186/can-not-kill-a-yarn-application-through-rest-api)